# How to display TinyMCE HTML view?

Tags: plugin-development, tinymce

I'm displaying TinyMCE in my plugin's settings using wp_tiny_mce():

```
<?php wp_tiny_mce( false , array("editor_selector" => "a_nice_textarea"));?>

<textarea class="a_nice_textarea" id="a_nice_textarea" name="a_nice_textarea"></textarea>
```

Everything works as expected but I want to display the HTML editor ONLY but wp_tiny_mce seems to output only the Visual Editor.

I know these are initial settings, but I've been playing with them for some time now without any luck:

```
// TinyMCE init settings
$initArray = array (
    'mode'                              => 'none',
    'onpageload'                        => 'switchEditors.edInit',
    'width'                             => '100%',
    'theme'                             => 'advanced',
    'skin'                              => 'wp_theme',
    'theme_advanced_buttons1'           => "$mce_buttons",
    'theme_advanced_buttons2'           => "$mce_buttons_2",
    'theme_advanced_buttons3'           => "$mce_buttons_3",
    'theme_advanced_buttons4'           => "$mce_buttons_4",
    'language'                          => "$mce_locale",
    'spellchecker_languages'            => "$mce_spellchecker_languages",
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_location'   => 'top',
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_align'      => 'left',
    'theme_advanced_statusbar_location' => 'bottom',
    'theme_advanced_resizing'           => true,
    'theme_advanced_resize_horizontal'  => false,
    'dialog_type'                       => 'modal',
    'relative_urls'                     => false,
    'remove_script_host'                => false,
    'convert_urls'                      => false,
    'apply_source_formatting'           => false,
    'remove_linebreaks'                 => true,
    'paste_convert_middot_lists'        => true,
    'paste_remove_spans'                => true,
    'paste_remove_styles'               => true,
    'gecko_spellcheck'                  => true,
    'entities'                          => '38,amp,60,lt,62,gt',
    'accessibility_focus'               => true,
    'tab_focus'                         => ':prev,:next',
    'content_css'                       => "$mce_css",
    'save_callback'                     => 'switchEditors.saveCallback',
    'wpeditimage_disable_captions'      => $no_captions,
    'plugins'                           => "$plugins"
);
```

Here's even a pretty good explanation of the problem and kind of a solution, but the code provided doesn't work for me either (and doesn't do exactly what I want to achieve):

http://keighl.com/post/switching-visualhtml-modes-with-tinymce/

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing sources of /wp-admin/ I realized that TinyMCE HTML view is just another textarea...

Anyways, here's the answer (everything works like a charm excepting the "img" button, but you can hide it easily with CSS - #ed_img {display: none} ).

```
<div id="postdivrich" class="postarea">

    <div id="editor-toolbar">
       <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/quicktags.js?ver=20110502'></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">edToolbar()</script>
    </div>

    <div id='editorcontainer'>
       <textarea rows='20' cols='40' tabindex='2' id='content' name="your_name"></textarea>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       edCanvas = document.getElementById('content');
    </script>

    <table id="post-status-info" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td><span>Textarea's description</span></td></tr></tbody></table>

</div>
```

Oh, and of course this is just a source "copypasta", don't forget to enqueue quicktags.js.